# Tomcat and Matlab MCR invalid MEX-file error

Tags: matlab, tomcat, ubuntu, mex, matlab-compiler

I have Tomcat 7 and MCR 8.3 installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 server.
Matlab is correctly installed, because I can execute some program, but when I try to execute others i have this error:

> Invalid MEX-file '/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/mcr/toolbox/matlab/sparfun/etree.mexa64': libmwarpack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I set the environment in my /etc/profile.d folder in this way:

```
MCR_ROOT=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83
export PATH=$PATH:$MCR_ROOT/bin:$MCR_ROOT/bin/glnxa64
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$MCR_ROOT/runtime/glnxa64:$MCR_ROOT/bin/glnxa64:$MCR_ROOT/toolbox/javabuilder:$MCR_ROOT/sys/os/glnxa64:$MCR_ROOT/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server:$MCR_ROOT/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64:$MCR_ROOT/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:$MCR_ROOT/mcr/toolbox/matlab/sparfun:$MCR_ROOT:mcr/toolbox
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export MCR_CACHE_ROOT=/home/bull/MCR/cache
export XAPPLRESDIR=$MCR_ROOT/X11/app-defaults
```

I was a bit frustrated and I added some folder more... 
The etree.mexa64 and libmwarpack.so files are correctly located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MATLAB, try setting the `LD_RUN_PATH` as you would for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  I think this is a small idiosyncrasy of MATLAB.

Comment: @zuno Great.  This problem seems to come up often with shared libraries linked to MEX files, but I can never find an answer to link to.  I'll probably refer to this Q&A in the future.