# matlab libstdc++.so.6 error (GLIBCXX_3.4.19 not found)

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I think the above error is well-known and I solved it in my virtual box by renaming the libstdc++.so.6 in the Matlab directory and instead using the one from my usr/lib folder.

But what if I do not have the rights to rename the file? How can I tell the compiler to link it to the library in my /usr/lib/.. folder?

Already, I added the /usr/lib/... path to die LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable, but it didn't work.

I use cmake to create my make files, is there any option to tell which library should be choosen?

Thank you

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28565482/2778484

Comment: I set it, but it does not work. Now, I found one work arround ...

Comment: `LD_RUN_PATH` didn't work either?  That's usually the solution when `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` doesn't.

Comment: I set the LD_RUN_PATH as environment variable and nothing changed with matlab. I posted the solution, which worked for me.

Comment: Glad you got a solution.  But this is not a compile time issue, so I don't think CMake settings are going to solve this for you.  But perhaps....

Answer (score 1):

I found one possibility, use LD_PRELOAD

-> $ LD_PRELOAD=path/libstdc++.so.6 matlab

would be happy if there is better way