# Control mex link options with g++ from command line

Tags: matlab, linker, g++, mex

I'm trying to link a library using mex from command line, or more exactly, from a makefile. I do this from a Makefile which I post here:

```
BDDM_MATLAB = @matlabhome@

MEXCC = $(BDDM_MATLAB)/bin/mex
MEXFLAGS = -v -largeArrayDims -O
MEXEXT = mexa64

TDIR = $(abs_top_srcdir)/test
IDIR = $(abs_top_srcdir)/src
LDIR = $(abs_top_srcdir)/lib

LOP1 = $(CUDA_LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

SOURCES := $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
mTESTS = $(addprefix $(TDIR)/, $(SOURCES:.cpp=.$(MEXEXT)))

all: $(TDIR) $(mTESTS)

$(OBJS) : %.o : %.cpp
    $(MEXCC) $(MEXFLAGS) -c -outdir ./ -output $@ $(CUDA_CFLAGS) -I$(IDIR) CFLAGS="\$$CFLAGS -std=c99" $^

$(mTESTS) : $(TDIR)/%.$(MEXEXT) : %.o
    $(MEXCC) $(MEXFLAGS) -L$(LDIR) -outdir $(TDIR) $^ $(LOP1) -lmpdcm LDFLAGS="-lcudart -lcuda"

.PHONY = $(TDIR)

$(TDIR):
    $(MKDIR_P) $@

clean:
    $(RM) *.o
```

libmpdcm is a static library that includes calls to two shared libraries libcuda and libcudart. My environment has

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

My make rule produces

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/mex -v -largeArrayDims -O -L/home/eaponte/projects/test_cpp/lib -outdir /home/eaponte/projects/test_cpp/test test_LayeredEEG.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart -lcuda  -lmpdcm LDFLAGS="-lcudart -lcuda"
```

This produces the following g++ command:

```
/usr/bin/gcc -lcudart -lcuda -shared  -O -Wl,--version-script,"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map" test_LayeredEEG.o  -lcudart  -lcuda  -lmpdcm   -L/home/eaponte/projects/test_cpp/lib  -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64   -L"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64" -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -lstdc++ -o /home/eaponte/projects/test_cpp/test/test_LayeredEEG.mexa64
```

The problem is that afterwards I get a linking error in Matlab:

```
Invalid MEX-file '/home/eaponte/projects/test_cpp/test/test_Fmri.mexa64': /home/eaponte/projects/test_cpp/test/test_Fmri.mexa64: undefined symbol: cudaFree
```

I know that the solution is simply to put the cuda libraries at the end of  the g++ command

```
/usr/bin/gcc -lcudart -lcuda -shared  -O -Wl,--version-script,"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map" test_LayeredEEG.o  -lmpdcm   -L/home/eaponte/projects/test_cpp/lib  -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64   -L"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64" -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -lstdc++ -lcudart  -lcuda -o /home/eaponte/projects/test_cpp/test/test_LayeredEEG.mexa64
```

How can achieve that running mex from command line (or from a Makefile)?

Comment: That's at runtime, right?  You may just need to adjust your LD_LIBRARY_PATH or LD_RUN_PATH for the MATLAB process (see [`setenv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setenv.html) to do it from inside MATLAB) to include the location of the CUDA runtimes.  Or if you want to link the static CUDA runtimes, you can just list the .a files at the end of the `mex` command.  Just a guess, so I'm not posting an answer.

Comment: None of the three commandlines entirely makes sense from a linkage
point of view, though I can see how the last one might solve the
linkage error. Please post the makefile in your question, and the
commandline you used to run the failing make, and the complete
console output of the failing make (from clean). Also, what is
the `libmpdcm` library and where does it come from?

Comment: @chappjc I have addressed your comments.

Comment: You've addressed @MikeKinghan's comments, I believe.  But I think you should try setting the environment variables I mentioned, inside MATLAB with the `setenv` command since this is a runtime error.

Comment: @eaponte From the makefile I believe I see the cause of the undefined symbol error. I should have time tomorrow to post an answer that it explains it (if I'm right) and how you can correctly control the order of build options.

Comment: @MikeKinghan's Sorry. The runtime libraries are in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH and running other code using cuda from matlab produces no error. Just for completeness I have added now to the question.

Comment: @eaponte I think you're mixing me up with chappjc. This is a linktime error, by definition not a runtime error because a linker error means you have no program to run.

Comment: @MikeKinghan From your first comment, should I change the order of the libraries in the linking step i.e. put my static library to the left of the shared libraries?

Comment: @eaponte I believe that linking `-lmpdcm` before `-lcudart` and `-lcuda` will solve the problem. Busy now but if it works I'll post explaining exactly why, and the rules for getting these things right in makefiles or commandlines.

Comment: @eaponte Did you try that?

Comment: @MikeKinghan No, the message "Invalid MEX-file" is a runtime error in MATLAB when you try to run a MEX file with various issues, like missing shared library dependencies, for example.  Dynamic linking, yes, but not at build-time.  I think eaponte should clarify when this message appears.  Again, I suggest also setting `LD_RUN_PATH` as I have seen [this be the solution in the past](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28565482/2778484).  So, it may be that `-lcudart_static` would do the trick too.

Comment: @chappjc You are quite right; I was forgetting for the moment he is building a shared library, not a program. The error message is from runtime failure of `dlopen` on his library. But it's reporting the discovery
of the bungled linkage and there's no runtime fix. His library doesn't even contain the information that it needs the cuda libraries until he fixes the linkage order.

Comment: @MikeKinghan No argument with that here!  :)  Good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to illuminate the problem and solution and offer some help in avoiding the like:

The fundamental rule of linkage with the GNU linker
that your problem makefile transgressed is: *In the commandline sequence of entities to be linked, ones that* **need** *symbol definitions
must appear* **before** *the ones that* **provide** *the definitions*.

An object file (`.o`) in the linkage sequence will be incorporated entire in the output executable,
regardless of whether or not it defines any symbols that the executable uses. A *library*
on the other hand, is merely examined to see if it provides any definitions for symbols
that are thus-far undefined, and only such definitions as it provides are linked into in
the executable (I am simplifying somewhat). Thus, linkage doesn't get started until *some* object file is seen,
and any library must appear after everything that needs definitions from it.

Breaches of this principle usually arise from inept bundling of some linker flag-options
and some library-options together into a `make`-variable and its placement in the linkage recipe,
with the result that the bundled options are interpolated at a position that is valid for
the flags but not valid for libraries. This was so in your problem makefile, with `LOP1` the
bad bundle.

In the typical case, the bundling causes all of the libraries to be placed before all the object files,
and never mentioned again. So the object files yield undefined symbol errors, because the libraries 
they require were seen by the linker before it had discovered any undefined symbols, and were ignored.
In your untypical case, it resulted in `libcudart` and `libcuda` being seen later than your only
object file `test_LayeredEEG.o` - which however required no symbols from them - but earlier than
the only thing that did require symbols from them, the library `libmpdcm`. So they were ignored,
and you built a `.mex64` shared library that had not been linked with them.

Long ago - pre-GCC 4.5 - shared libraries (like `libcudart` and `libcuda`) were exempt
from the requirement that they should be *needed*, at the point when the linker sees them,
in order to be linked. They were linked regardless, like object files, and the belief that
this is so has not entirely died out. It is not so. By default, shared libraries and
static libraries alike are linked if and only if needed-when-seen.

To avoid such traps it is vastly helpful to understand the canonical nomenclature of
the `make` variables involved in compilation and linkage and their semantics, and
their canonical use in compilation and linkage recipes for `make`. Mex is a 
manipulator of C/C++/Fortran compilers that adds some commandline options of its own:
for `make` purposes, it is another compiler. For the options that it inherits from and 
passes to the underlying compiler, you want to adhere to the usage for that compiler in `make` recipes.

These are the `make` variables most likely to matter to you and their meanings:

- `CC` = Your C compiler, e.g. `gcc`
- `FC` = Your Fortran compiler, e.g. `gfortran`
- `CXX` = Your C++ compiler, e.g. `g++`.
- `LD` = Your linker, e.g. `ld`. But you should know that only for specialized uses
  should the linker be directly invoked. Normally, the real linker is invoked on your
  behalf by the compiler. It can deduce from the options that you pass it whether you
  want compiling done or linking done, and will invoke the appropriate tool. When you
  want linking done, it will quietly augment the linker options that you pass with
  additional ones that it would be very tiresome to specify, but which ensure
  that the linkage acquires all the the correct flags and libraries for the language of the
  program you are linking. Consequently almost always, *specify your compiler as your
  linker*.
- `AR` = Your archiving tool (static library builder)
- `CFLAGS` = Options for C compilation
- `FFLAGS` = Options for Fortran compilation
- `CXXFLAGS` = Options for C++ compilation
- `CPPFLAGS` = Options for the C preprocessor, for any compiler that uses it. *Avoid the common mistake of writing `CPPFLAGS` when you mean `CXXFLAGS`*
- `LDFLAGS` = Options for linkage, *N.B. excluding library options*, `-l<name>`
- `LDLIBS` = Library options for linkage, `-l<name>`

And the canonical `make` rules for compiling and linking:

C source file `$<` to object file `$@`:

```
$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $@ $<
```

Free-from Fortran file `$<` to object file `$@`, with preprocessing:

```
$(FC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(FFLAGS) -c $@ $<
```

(without preprocessing, remove `$(CPPFLAGS)`)

C++ source file `$<` to object file `$@`:

```
$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $@ $<
```

Linking object files $^ into an executable $@:

```
$(<compiler>) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)
```

If you can as much as possible write makefiles so that a) you have assigned the right options to the right variables from
this glossary, and b) used the canonical `make` recipes, then your path will be much smoother.

**And BTW...**

Your makefile has the following bug:

```
.PHONY = $(TDIR)
```

This is apparently an attempt to make `$(TDIR)` a [phony target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html),
but the syntax is wrong. It should be:

```
.PHONY: $(TDIR)
```

what the assignment does is simply create a `make` variable called, `.PHONY` with the value of `$(TDIR)`,
and does not make `$(TDIR)` a phony target.

Which is fortunate, because `$(TDIR)` is your output directory and not a phony
target.

You wish to ensure that `make` creates `$(TDIR)` before you need to output anything into
it, but you do not want it to a normal prequisite of those artefacts, which would oblige
`make` to rebuild them whenever the timestamp of `$(TDIR)` was touched. That is presumably
why you thought to make it a phony target.

What you actually want `$(TDIR)` to be is an [order-only prerequsite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html)
of the `$(mTESTS)` that will be output there. The way to do that is to amend the `$(mTESTS)` rule to be:

```
$(mTESTS) : $(TDIR)/%.$(MEXEXT) : %.o | $(TDIR)
```

This will cause `$(TDIR)` to be made, if needed, before `$(mTESTS)` is made, but
nevertheless `$(TDIR)` will not be considered in determining whether `$(mTESTS)` *does*
need to be made.

On the other hand, the targets `all` and `clean` *are* phony targets: no such artefacts
are to be made, so you should tell `make` so with:

```
.PHONY: all clean
```

Comment: thank you for your thorough answer, for the recommendations, and for pointing out the bug. I see that my makefile is very bloated but I'm not yet quite proefficient writing them.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the problem was in the order of the dynamic libraries in the compilation flags. After searching the reason for this I found in SO that static libraries need to be linked taking into account the order of dependency. In my case, the library libmpdc had dependencies on libcuda and libcudart but was on the left. The solution is to swap the order in the makefile from:

```
$(mTESTS) : $(TDIR)/%.$(MEXEXT) : %.o
    $(MEXCC) $(MEXFLAGS) -L$(LDIR) -outdir $(TDIR) $^ $(LOP1) -lmpdcm LDFLAGS="-lcudart -lcuda"
```

to

```
$(mTESTS) : $(TDIR)/%.$(MEXEXT) : %.o
    $(MEXCC) $(MEXFLAGS) -L$(LDIR) -outdir $(TDIR) $^ -lmpdcm $(LOP1)
```

Comment: I'm glad you found your answer.  Finding the right library listing order in Linux can be a pain.  But I still wanted you to clarify when you saw "Invalid MEX-file".  When you tried to run it, correct?  I've always seen that at run-time, not build time.

Comment: @chappjc That's right, it linked without producing an error, but during runtime it reported the missing library.